# Header file not being included

Tags: c++, header, include, header-files

I'm currently working on a school project with a small group of people and have hit a brick wall regarding #include.  So, the program we're making is a text based RPG style fight simulator.  We have the files:
source.cpp, menu.h, monster.h, player.h, and item.h.  The problem is that monster.h is not detecting class player despite having #include "player.h".  In fact, it wont import menu.h either (although it doesn't need to), but doesn't have trouble importing item.h.  We have shown our code to the professor as well and he couldn't figure it out either. The code listed below is how we have our header files formatted, please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong. Thank you

## Monster.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include "menu.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "Item.h"
using namespace std;
class Monster {}
```

## player.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Item.h"
#include "menu.h"
using namespace std;
class Monster;
class Player : public Monster {}
```

Comment: Don't put `using namespace std;` in header files.

Comment: Besides putting `using namespace std;` in header files, which breaks a whole bunch of things, you are inheriting from `Monster` without defining the class. You're only forward-declaring it, and including the header file before the definition of the class. And if it is actually true, what you claimed, that your alleged C++ professor couldn't figure it out, it's time to find a more competent C++ professor.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about namespace std and headers.  I had a programmer buddy suggest that I forward-declare class Monster since the way we had it before would have initiated an infinite loop I guess (monster.h included in player.h and player.h included in monster.h).  It didn't really work, so I'm still at square one.  About my professor, he's not the best, but come to think of it I'm taking my classmate's word that he talked to the professor about it already.  I'll try asking him about it myself and see if I get anything.